# How to marshal XML

Tags: go, marshalling

I have two structs in order to marshal into XML

```
//Accounts ...
type Accounts struct {
    XMLName     xml.Name `xml:"account"`
    AccNumber   string   `xml:"iban"`

}

//Accounts ...
type AccountsList struct {
    XMLName    xml.Name   `xml:"response"`
    ResultCode string     `xml:"resultCode"`
    Accounts   []Accounts `xml:"result"`
}
```

I'm getting next xml structure:

```
<response>
    <resultCode>...</resultCode>
    <account>
        <iban>...</iban>
    </account>
    <account>
        <iban>...</iban>
    </account>
</response>
```

But I need also `<result>` tag, so I need next xml:

```
<response>
    <resultCode>...</resultCode>
    <result>
        <account>
            <iban>...</iban>
        </account>
        <account>
            <iban>...</iban>
        </account>
    <result>  
</response>
```

Why Golang XML marshaller is ignoring this thing `xml:"result"` in `AccountsList` structure? 
**Is it possible to get result I want without using third structure**?

Comment: "Why Golang XML marshaller is ignoring this thing xml:"result" in AccountsList structure?" Because the tag on the xml.Name field of the marshalled type is prefered over the tag on the field containing that type, even if the field is a slice of that type. The order of preference is specified here: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the field tag name from `result` to `result>account`:

```
type AccountsList struct {
    XMLName    xml.Name   `xml:"response"`
    ResultCode string     `xml:"resultCode"`
    Accounts   []Accounts `xml:"result>account"`
}
```

This will wrap your `accounts` slice with `result` tag.

See: https://play.golang.org/p/E2oJeO81wKh

Answer (score 0):

Please go thorough this below code, I've tested it on go play ground and it doesn't give me any error.

```
func main() {
var al AccountsList
output, err := xml.MarshalIndent(al, "  ", "    ")
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground", err)
    fmt.Println(string(output))

}
```

You can test it too using this [link](https://play.golang.org/p/DGAB0qhGtpH).